# Power BI - If a date is between 2 dates using relationships

Tags: powerbi, relationship, reporting, data-modeling, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to determine if a date is between 2 other dates that are is 2 different tables using
Power BI.

For simplicity, here is the model that I have :
[image]

TableB is the bridge table between TableA and TableC.
I have an inactive relationship between tableA and TableC.

I have tried the following logic to check if TableC.createdDate is between TableA.startDate and TableA.endDate :

- Create a calculated column in TableC, but I was not able to access columns in TableA
- Create a calculated column in TableB, but I was having blank results, which is not suppose to happen

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using `USERELATIONSHIP` to force your calculated column to use the inactive relationship to TableA? [documentation link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/userelationship-function-dax)

So something like

```
CALCULATE(
  {{created date is >start and <end}}, 
  USERELATIONSHIP('TableA'[TableB_ID],'TableC'[TableB_ID]
)
```